# Cookie is not saved if system power is interrupted

Tags: javascript, cookies, raspbian

On Raspberry Pi Raspbian Chromium Kiosk-Mode, I am saving a cookie:

```
document.cookie = "currentImage=" + currentImage + ";expires=2038-01-19, 03:14:08 UTC; path=/"
```

Then after a while the power to the Pi is cut. When the system is restored, the cookie cannot be read. Is there a way to persist the cookie in JS?

Comment: Try `;expires=2038-01-19, 03:14:06 UTC;`. According to Wikipedia, anytime after `03:14:07 UTC` won't work. Ref:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: This did not help.

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Comment: I havn't been able to try it yet

Comment: And what answer covered points? Is something missing or not clear?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have misconfigured profile (Your profile that saves all data inside including the cookies). Check this [blog post](https://obrienlabs.net/setup-raspberry-pi-kiosk-chromium/) for bare config.

Also, make sure there is a directory with this path `~/.config/chromium` (This is the default directory for your profile data). And, you can also this option to set user data dir explicitly

```
chromium-browser --user-data-dir=DIR
```

> **--user-data-dir=DIR**
>
> Specifies the directory that user data (your "profile") is kept in.  Defaults to ~/.config/chromium  . **Separate instances of Chromium must  use separate  user data  directories**; repeated invocations of chromium-browser will reuse an existing process for a given user data directory.

Personally, I didn't face this problem before but I tried to give you some insights and keys to the solution. Therefore, I highly recommend if you still face the problem to check this list for [chromium different options](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)